# Can't Pass bashrc defined arguments to the terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, python, c++

I am trying to write a code that automate some of Nasa's Heasoft program - this doesn't matter -,

heainit is definied in the bashrc as:

```
export HEADAS=~/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31
alias heainit='. $HEADAS/headas-init.sh'
```

so whenever I write `heainit` on terminal it works pretty fine. However, whenever I tried to pass "heainit" to the terminal through c++ or Python, the code it self works but it doesn't initiate the program!

in c++ I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){ string ind, outd;
const char* heainit = "/home/karim/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/headas-init.sh" ; 
system(heainit);
return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(string, char*){
string ind, outd;
std::string HEADAS = "/home/karim/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31";
std::string str = std::string(". //") + HEADAS + std::string("/headas-init.sh");
const char *c = str.c_str(". /home/karim/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/heafas-init.sh");
system(const char* c);
return 0;
}
```

and

in python I tried:

```
import os
import subprocess
os.system("heainit")
```

and
subprocess.run("heainit",capture_output=True)

and

```
HEADAS=~/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31
heainit="." + "\t" + HEADAS + "/headas-init.sh"
subprocess.run(heainit, shell=True)
```

My latest attempt was to write a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HEADAS=~/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31
export HEADAS
alias heainit='. $HEADAS/headas-init.sh'

heainit
```

and the prompt gives the following:
./hea.sh: line 6: heainit: command not found

whenever I execute any of the aforementioned codes with anyother command like "ls -l" for instance it works perfectly :"))
I don't know how should I pass this argument(it should be followed by others when the program is initiated) to the terminal yet and I don't know what i lack to go. Maybe the problem is trivial but i'm stuck there for a long time now.

Comment: There are at least two layers of issues here: (1) the C `system` function and Python's subprocess with `shell=True` almost certainly invoke `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash` and (2) shell aliases are not expanded by default unless the shell is interactive.

Comment: *"I am trying to write a code"* - Bash scripting is technically on-topic here, but if the question is more about writing code than using Ubuntu, you should probably ask this question on StackOverflow.  Know your audience.

Answer (score 0):

Bash aliases are not "real" executables and cannot be called from outside of bash.  You either need to access environment variable(s) from within your C++/Python/whatever program to rebuild the full path to `headas-init.sh`, create an actual bash script that calls `headas-init.sh` and then call that script in your own program, or call `/bin/bash` and pass in your alias as code to be executed using something like `-c` bash argument.